# git pull will move the local branch to the latest commit?

Tags: git, branch, pull

I have a local branch, which is `topic`, this branch is labelled on the latest local commit, for example commit version 3, I stay on `topic` branch, not `master` branch, then I do the `git pull`, there are other two commits(version 4 and version 5) showed up and the `topic` is moved  to the latest commits, is it right?  Should I stay at branch `master` and do the git pull?  What is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the man pages says:

> git-pull - Fetch from and merge with another repository or a local branch

So, basically `git pull` is a shortcut for `git fetch` followed by `git merge`. That's why it *will* move your branch reference to the latest commit. If you were on `master` then `master` would be updated.

If you don't want your branches to be updated, just use `git fetch` instead.

Comment: when we do the clone, there is already a master local branch is created automatcally, but why we need to create a new one? is this local master is special?

Comment: @user2131316 What to you mean “create a new one”? It wasn't mentioned in your question.

Comment: Anyway, you have in your repo both your branches and remote ones. That is, you've got “master” which is _your_ master branch, and “origin/master” which is the remote master branch as it was seen during last `git fetch`. When you do `git fetch` you update `remote/*` branches, but then you'll have to checkout your own branches and update them manually to set to commits pointed by their remote counterparts. `git pull` does this for you automatically for some branches, specified in your configs (those are called “tracking”).

Comment: yes, it is not in my question, I was thinking about it after I saw your answer. "create a new one" what I mean is: when we do the clone remote repo, it will create a local master branch for us, but is this local master special? because I saw lots of people create a new local branch, why?